# If the text contains emoji, Range is nil from swift

Tags: swift

The text "Welcome my application..❣️" does not make sense during the `NSRange` and `Range` tests. If ❣️ is included, Range is returned as `nil`, and I wonder why.

```
func testA() {
        let testStr = "Welcome my application..❣️"

        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testStr.count)
        let wrapRange = Range(range, in: testStr)

        let testStrB = "Welcome my application.."

        let rangeB = NSRange(location: 0, length: testStrB.count)
        let wrapRangeB = Range(rangeB, in: testStrB)

        print("wrapRange: \(wrapRange) wrapRangeB: \(wrapRangeB)")
}
```

RESULT:

```
wrapRange: nil wrapRangeB: Optional(Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 1)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 1572864)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"❣️" is a single “extended grapheme cluster”, but two UTF-16 code units:

```
print("❣️".count)       // 1
print("❣️".utf16.count) // 2
```

`NSRange` counts UTF-16 code units (which are the “characters” in an `NSString`) , therefore the correct way to create an `NSRange` comprising the complete range of a Swift string is

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testStr.utf16.count)
```

or better (since Swift 4):

```
let range = NSRange(testStr.startIndex..., in: testStr)
```

---

*Explanation:* In your code (simplified here)

```
let testStr = "❣️"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testStr.count)
print(range) // {0, 1}
```

creates an `NSRange` describing a single UTF-16 code unit. This cannot be converted to a `Range<String.Index>` in `testStr` because its first `Character` consists of *two* UTF-16 code units:

```
let wrapRange = Range(range, in: testStr)
print(wrapRange)  // nil
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but the NSRange that the OP creates is not actually tied to a string though. He just takes the string length and creates an NSRange using that, doesn't he? Also, Swift 5 switched from UTF-16 string representation to UTF-8. I see that it helped the OP, so I'm missing something, but could you elaborate a bit, please, if you don't mind?

Comment: @FreeNickname: See update. This is unrelated to the internal representation of String.

Comment: @MartinR Ugh... I somehow managed to completely overlook that an `NSRange` is created and then converted to a Swift Range passing in the string as a parameter. Got to sleep more. Thanks a lot for the explanation!